# Lock down a program so it has no access to outside files, like a virus scanner does

Tags: python, windows, linux, macos, permissions

I would like to launch an untrusted application programmatically, so I want to remove the program's ability to access files, network, etc. Essentially, I want to restrict it so its only interface to the rest of the computer is stdin and stdout.

Can I do that? Preferably in a cross-platform way but I sort of expect to have to do it differently for each OS. I'm using Python, but I'm willing to write this part in a lower level or more platform integrated language if necessary.

The reason I need to do this is to write a distributed computing infrastructure. It needs to download a program, execute it, piping data to stdin, and returning data that it receives on stdout to the central server. But since the program it downloads is untrusted, I want to restrict it to only using stdin and stdout.

Comment: Is the "untrusted application" also written in Python or could it be any application?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: [python_security.pdf](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&srcid=1oDb9LEQd8hHT2Ni1VlCCrH0ODwoprEZ1bsPG58CmbWXRYL8hKBxf4GjG1n9W&hl=en) Can't get the original file...

Comment: A virus scanner doesn't lock down an application. It _scans_ it (scannee is passive). You probably mean some popular personal firewall type of programs.

Comment: @WTP the untrusted code could be any language

Comment: What's wrong with using a virtual machine to run the untrusted code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You can run an inferior process through [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) (essentially you act as a debugger) and you hook on system calls and determine whether they should be allowed or not.

codepad.org does this for instance, see: [about codepad](http://codepad.org/about). It uses the [geordi](http://weegen.home.xs4all.nl/eelis/geordi/) supervisor to execute the untrusted code.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is not really.  Consider a C program, in which the program opens a log file by grabbing the next available file descriptor.  Your program, in order to stop this, would need to somehow monitor this, and block it.  Depending on the robustness of the untrusted program, this could cause a fatal crash, or inhibit harmless functionality.  There are many other similar issues to this one that make what you are trying to do hard.

I would recommend looking into [sandboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29) solutions already available.  In particular, a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) can be very useful for testing out untrusted code.  If you can't find anything that meets your needs, your best bet is to probably deal with this at the kernel level, or with something a bit closer to the hardware such as C.

Comment: While the program I want to run is untrusted, its not an arbitrary program, it is supposed to follow a defined interface that only uses stdin and stdout. If the program tries to access any resources besides stdin and stdout, it _should_ crash.

Comment: While that eliminates the problem I used above, what if the program tries to access the network?  There are a number of ways it could accomplish this, and you would be hard-pressed to monitor them all from a more simple program.  If you can explain a bit more about your situation, someone might be able to suggest something a bit more helpful.

Comment: The reason I need to do this is to write a distributed computing infrastructure. It needs to download a program, execute it, piping data to stdin, and returning data that it receives on stdout to the central server. But since the program it downloads is untrusted, I want to restrict it to only using stdin and stdout. I've also added this info to my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can run untrusted apps in chroot and block them from using network with an iptables rule (for example, owner --uid-owner match)

But really, virtual machine is more reliable and on modern hardware performance impact is negligible.